# jasmine serivce function not returning mock value

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am work on the angular testing for first time and from monring i struggling to test this. I added both modules inside TestBed and injected but real method is always called instead of returning value from `getMockFeatureState()`. Please help fix this. Thannks

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ HttpClientModule ],
      providers: [ FeatureToggleService, ConfigService]
    });
  });

  it('should return values based on mock feature state', () => {
    const featureService = TestBed.inject(FeatureToggleService);
    const configService = TestBed.inject(ConfigService);
    const mockFeaturesSpy = spyOn(configService, 'getMockFeatures')
        .and.returnValue(getMockFeatureState());
    expect(featureService.isFeatureEnabled('feature1')).toBeFalsy();
    expect(featureService.isFeatureEnabled('feature2')).toBeFalsy();
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently faced the same issue in one of my tests. The order of `TestBed.inject` was the issue. If FeatureToggleService requires ConfigService. You have to inject ConfigService first and mock it before injecting the featureService. You can try

```
  it('should return values based on mock feature state', () => {
    const configService = TestBed.inject(ConfigService);
    const mockFeaturesSpy = spyOn(configService, 'getMockFeatures')
        .and.returnValue(getMockFeatureState());
    const featureService = TestBed.inject(FeatureToggleService);
    expect(featureService.isFeatureEnabled('feature1')).toBeFalsy();
    expect(featureService.isFeatureEnabled('feature2')).toBeFalsy();
  });
```

Comment: This was issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I also moved the injection of dependency service into beforeEach block like mentioned in other answer so that it can be applied for other tests too